# Purpose of with in sentence

Tags: prepositions

> This year we were very unlucky because we played **with** one player less against Barcelona.

I don’t understand why “with” is used in this sentence. I thought there should be a noun after “with” but there is no a noun. I think “less” doesn’t describe “player” here. Or I wonder would it be better if I use this sentence without “with” by using “less” as an adverb.Would the meaning change?

Answer (score 1):

The preposition phrase is *with one player less*. It acts as a modifier of the sentence, telling the conditions we played under.

*one player less* is a noun phrase. It works the same as
played with five players
played with all our players

A noun or a noun phrase can be the object of a preposition. Examples of noun phrases as objects of prepositions:
on muddy ground
for all time
in each case
at every turn

"We played one player less/short." works, but to me it's harder to understand.

Comment: @JackO'Elaherty I have a question. in a PP "with one player less",  is word 'less' an adjective and does it modify one player?

Comment: I think "one" is a determiner, and "less" is an adverb that modifies it. Or, the entire phrase "one less" may be the determiner - I'm not sure.